# Math operations with lists using integers from nested lists

Tags: python, list, math, numpy, integer

I have:

```
List1 = [100, 200, 300]

List2 = [[34,35,36],[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2]]
```

How can I sum each element of `List1` with each element inside each list in `List2`?

I want:

```
List3 = [[134,135,136],[200,201,202,203],[300,301,302]]
```

I tried doing something along the lines of:

```
for i in List2:
    [sum(x) for x in zip(List1, i)]
```

but I'm not getting the right answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Conventionally you should post a [mcve]; in this case, because variable names can't have spaces, your setup code can't be copied and pasted.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use list comprehension(s), you could write:

```
>>> [[x + a for a in lst] for x, lst in zip(List1, List2)]
[[134, 135, 136], [200, 201, 202, 203], [300, 301, 302]]
```

(This assumes that both lists are the same length; if not you may want to use `zip_longest` from the itertools library to pad out the shorter list.)

Comment: No problem - glad it helped!

Comment: What if the value to add is a 0, ie `[300]` and `[0]` = `300` (0 being the only element in that list) it is not doing that, and skipping over to `[400]`

Comment: Hmmm... It shouldn't skip any numbers. What are `List1` and `List2` in this example?

Comment: So `List1=[0,100,200,300,400]` and `List2=[[0,1,2],[2,3,4],[51,52,53,54,55],[0],[12,13]]`

Comment: It still works for me: I get the list `[[0, 1, 2], [102, 103, 104], [251, 252, 253, 254, 255], [300], [412, 413]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I may suggest a slightly different implementation:

```
List3 = map(lambda x, y: [z + x for z in y], List1, List2)
```

Comment: What if the value to add is a 0, ie `[300]` and `[0]` should equal `300` (0 being the only element in that list) it is not doing that, and skipping over to `[400]`